# bash function - loop on params provided by the user

Tags: bash

I have the following method (gcloud port forwarding), which I call it as the following:

`gport machine-name 8080`

I want to pass change it and pass multiple ports:

`gport machine-name 8080 8081 8070 ....`

how can I loop the second line in the function and and replace the `$2` with the port number.

```
#!/bin/bash

G_PROJECT=prj-2025
G_ZONE=us-central1-a
G_USER=deployer


gport(){
   IP=$(gcloud compute instances describe $1 --zone $G_ZONE  --format='get(networkInterfaces[0].networkIP)' --project $G_PROJECT)
   gcloud compute ssh  --project $G_PROJECT  --zone $G_ZONE $G_USER@$1 -- -NL  127.0.0.1:$2:$IP:$2
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can "remove" the first argument using `shift`. `$@` will then be a list of ports you can iterate easily.

```
gport(){
  host=$1
  shift
  IP=$(gcloud compute instances describe "$host" --zone "$G_ZONE" --format='get(networkInterfaces[0].networkIP)' --project "$G_PROJECT")
  for port in "$@"; do
    gcloud compute ssh --project "$G_PROJECT" --zone "$G_ZONE" "$G_USER@$host" -- -NL "127.0.0.1:$port:$IP:$port"
  done
}
```